# How does offset in XGBoost is handled in binary:logistic objective function

Tags: r, machine-learning, boosting, offset

I am working on a mortality prediction (binary outcome) problem with “base mortality probability” as my offset in the `XGboost` problem.
I have used `gbtree` booster and binary:logistic objective function. In my data data I have multiple observations/records having same X values but different offset values.

As per my understanding (please correct me, if wrong) the `XGBoost` under binary:logistic setup tries to fit a model of below representation. $\log(p/1-p) = \text{offset} + F(x)$. Where $F(x)$ is optimized (for a specific loss function) using splits with various $X$ values.

Thus, when the $X$ values are exactly same, to get the $F(x)$, I can use the predicted output (with outputmargin = True option) and subtract the offset from here. However, when I got the output, it turned out in the above mentioned approach, I am getting different values $F(X)$ for a same set $X$. I believe the way offset is handled internally in the XGBoost is different from my understanding. Can anyone explain me this method/mathematical formulation of handling offset.

I am specifically interested in extracting the value of $F(x)$ (as this is additional information the model is providing) by adjusting the model prediction from the offset values.

Here are the sample codes in R (I have run equivalent code in Python also which led to similar outcome):

```r
library(xgboost)
x1 = runif(1000)
y1 = as.numeric(runif(1000)>.8)
y2 = as.numeric(runif(1000)>.8)
off1 = runif(1000)
off2 = runif(1000)

# stacking the data to have same X values
x= c(x1, x1)
y = c(y1, y2)
off = c(off1 ,off2)

length(unique(off)) # shows unique 2000 values
length(unique(x)) # shows unique 1000 values, i.e. 
                  # each X is repeated once (as expected)

fulldata = cbind.data.frame(x, y, off)

train_dMtrix = xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(x),
                           label = y,
                           base_margin = off)

params_list=list(booster = "gblinear", objective = "binary:logistic", 
    eta = 0.05, max_depth= 4, min_child_weight = 10, 
    eval_metric = 'logloss')

set.seed(100)

xgbmodel = xgb.train(params = params_list, data = train_dMtrix, 
                     nrounds=100)

# Getting the prediction in link format
fulldata$Predicted_link = predict(xgbmodel, train_dMtrix, 
                              outputmargin = TRUE)
# Assuming Predicted_link = offset + F(x), calculating F(x) 
# for each values of X
fulldata$F_x = fulldata$Predicted_link - fulldata$off
# As per my understanding, since the F(X) in purely independent of offset, 
# the model predictions of F_x (not the predicted probability) 
# should be exactly same for same values of x, 
# irrespective of the corresponding offsets. Given I have 1000 
# distinct X values, I'm expecting 1000 distinct F_x values

length(unique(fulldata$F_x)) # shows almost 2000 unique values, 
                             # which is contrary to my expectation.
```

Comment: Can you please give a minimal reproducible example of what you describe? (Use some fake data, on a simplified example) It is not obvious what you mean by "*I am getting different values F(X) for a same set X*". But yeah, XGBoost will use the `base_margin` values as initial margin prediction and boost from then onwards.

Comment: @usεr11852, I have updated my question with reproducible code.